# scrabble challenge from openhatch wiki...issue getting the rack

Tags: python, project, argparse, args, sys

The area I need help with is 
Step 2: from this link for a project
http://wiki.openhatch.org/Scrabble_challenge#Step_2:_get_the_rack
my code so far is:

```
import argparse
import sys
file=open('sowpods.txt','r')
scores = {"a": 1, "c": 3, "b": 3, "e": 1, "d": 2, "g": 2,
     "f": 4, "i": 1, "h": 4, "k": 5, "j": 8, "m": 3,
     "l": 1, "o": 1, "n": 1, "q": 10, "p": 3, "s": 1,
     "r": 1, "u": 1, "t": 1, "w": 4, "v": 4, "y": 4,
     "x": 8, "z": 10}

parser=argparse.ArgumentParser(description='designed to help in scrabble')
#command line interface using argparse module
parser.add_argument("word",help="input your letters")#adds the argument with 
description
args=parser.parse_args()
print(args.word)
```

i cant figure out who to print an error message if someone doesnt input the letter, i tried doing

```
if args.word=='':
    print('error need letters')
    sys.exit()
```

but that doesnt work. thanks for any help.

Comment: argparse already throws an error if not enough arguments are provided (as in your case)

Comment: yeah i would like to alter the error message however

Comment: in the future, please show actual vs. expected output. it makes your questions much more answerable

Comment: sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

First, make the answer optional to avoid argparse throwing errors. If no argument is passed, it will be set to `None` (or another default).

```
parser=argparse.ArgumentParser(description='designed to help in scrabble')
parser.add_argument("word",help="input your letters", nargs='?')  # nargs
args=parser.parse_args()

if args.word is None: # check equality to None
    print('error need letters')
    sys.exit()
```

Comment: Awesome! any documentation to explain nargs! i used an if else argument to account for if the letters presetn and to print them in lower casse and it works beautifully